# Is it possible to install virtualenv without python3 on debian?

Tags: debian, python

I'm trying to install virtualenv without installing python3 on my debian jessie machine. I'm new to debian being a gentoo native. I'm trying to install virtualenv with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

And this is pulling in python3. Upon further investigation it appears `python-virtualenv` pulls in `python-pip-whl` which pulls in `python-chardet-whl` which pulls in `python3-pkg-resources` which pulls in `python3`. Am I misunderstanding this because I'm new to debian and `python-virtualenv` is not actually designed for python2 or is there something wrong with the dependencies (a bug perhaps)?

```
$ apt-cache depends python-virtualenv --recurse
python-virtualenv
  Depends: python
  Depends: python-pip-whl
  Depends: python-pkg-resources
  Depends: python-setuptools-whl
  Recommends: virtualenv
...
python-pip-whl
  Depends: python-chardet-whl
  Depends: python-colorama-whl
  Depends: python-distlib-whl
  Depends: python-html5lib-whl
  Depends: python-requests-whl
  Depends: python-setuptools-whl
  Depends: python-six-whl
  Depends: python-urllib3-whl
...
python-chardet-whl
  Depends: python3-pkg-resources
...
python3-pkg-resources
  Depends: <python3:any>
    python3
  Depends: <python3:any>
    python3
  Suggests: python3-setuptools
  Conflicts: python-pkg-resources
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a bug in the dependencies of the debian python packaging. The virtualenv package for python2 should by no means be dependent on python3.

A workaround here is to install virtualenv with pip:

pip install virtualenv

To get pip just do "apt-get install python-pip".